# Krajee JqueryPlugin file input - disable validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Krajee JQueryPlugin Bootstrap and I have a modal edit form. The file is already selected, but when I submit the form, I have the following error message:

```
"You must select at least one file to upload "
```

How could I disable this validation upload? I do not want to send Image.

This is my code:

```
$('#file-0a').fileinput({       
        showUpload: false,
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
        initialCaption: 'img48.png',
        initialPreview: [
            "/images/img48.png"
        ],
        overwriteInitial: true
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your input tag (id="file-0a") and add the attribute data-min-file-count="1" to 0
something like this

```
<input id="file-0a" data-min-file-count="0"/>
```